# How to prevent Browser cache on Angular 7 site?

Tags: angular, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, angular7

I have a web application in a production environment. The users are using it every day, when I publish an update and a user comes back to the web application he/she views the old version of the web application. He needs to refresh the browser to load the new version. How can I solve this problem? I cannot tell hundreds of users to refresh the page every time I publish an update (3-4 times a week). I have used following to build my front end application: Angular7 with angular-cli.

Comment: Where is your application hosted? You will need to ensure that your index.html is not stored in the browser cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ng build --aot --output-hashing=all
```

This makes a hash that must match the server side. If the cached version of the front end is not the same as the hash, they get a new version of the app. This assumes you are using the standard way of building using the angular CLI.

If you aren't, you could always try something hackish like the following (untested)

```
@Component({
templateUrl: './app/something/something/something.html?v=' + Math.random()
stylesUrls: ['./app/something/something/something.html?v=' + Math.random()]
})
```

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday, but now i am getting the same error, browser cache issue still

Comment: are you sure you are using the right URL? If you are working with a full stack app in the backend, the server side might be serving somthing other than the /dist folder. For instance, Visual Studio IIS in debug mode will serve up files that it is configured for rather than the dist folder (by default as I remember in 2016)

Comment: One thing to check is to build your app and with these output hashing settings. Then opening the dist folder and making sure the files have random looking ending cancelled on. This will ensure a server side build tool is not overwriting the files.

Comment: No problem. If it ends up working let me know. accepting the answer if as well ;)

Comment: thank you so much Goku its working for me    ng build --aot --output-hashing=all

Comment: @Goku --output-hashing=all  is not creating unique hashes