# Avoid caching of require resource in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

in my Angular project I use the require function to use an external script

```
require('../scripts/my-merge-images.js')
```

but I don't want to cache this script in client browser, there is a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advice for your answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Browser cache on Angular 7 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024779/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-on-angular-7-site)

Comment: @PvriaAnsari nope my question is different, I don't want to cache only this single script file on client browser, always and not only after a build.